# White bar below toolbar

Tags: android, xml

So i have an app with a toolbar and a whitebar appears bellow the toolbar(screenshot at the end), i dont want that bar there i tried adding maxHeight to see if it worked but no luck 
here is my style and v21/style xmls

style

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

v21/Style

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>

</style>
```

and here is an example of the toolbar in the same activity as the screenshot bellow
there is also a v21/layout file for this activity as it is the using to test but its exactly the same (needed one to be able to set the background color)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".ServiciosActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_servicios">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:maxHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

    <!-- #4674B7 -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/facebookm16blanco2" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webViewServicios"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't get the question! Do you want or no that white bar below your toolbar?

Comment: We need the entire layout file.

Comment: @G.Ciardini i dont want the bar, edited the post to clarify

Comment: @TheWanderer there isnt much more in the layout file but i edited the code sample to be the whole file

Comment: Why not just set the Toolbar's height to `?android:attr/actionBarSize` instead of setting min and max heights to the same?

Comment: i did, at first, i was just testing different things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your margin on the WebView:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webViewServicios"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" <!-- this -->
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
```

Remove the margin and you won't have a white bar.

Comment: thanks you were absolutely, i was sure the webview was right so i didnt even think about it, thanks